# SQL UPDATE and SET on phpmyadmin depending on the values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update, case

Would like to know how come my SQL update case is not functioning correctly.
I already have values:

```
$usrcustomerid = 110;
$search = 'face';
```

Looking for a fix on my CASE in SET because there is no update when this SQL triggers

**SQL Update code**

```
   public function UpdateUserSearch($db, $usrcustomerid, $search) {
   $stmt = $db->prepare(
     " UPDATE usr_customer
       SET search_counter = (CASE WHEN search_counter = 1 THEN 2
                                  WHEN search_counter = 2 THEN 3
                                  WHEN search_counter = 3 THEN 1 END),

           search1 = (CASE WHEN search_counter = 1 THEN $search END),
           search2 = (CASE WHEN search_counter = 2 THEN $search END),
           search3 = (CASE WHEN search_counter = 3 THEN $search END)
       WHERE usrcustomerid = $usrcustomerid "
   );

   $stmt->bindValue(':usrcustomerid', $usrcustomerid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
   $stmt->bindValue(':search', $search, PDO::PARAM_STR);
   $stmt->execute();
   $rowAffected = $stmt->rowCount();

   return $rowAffected;
 }
```

**table usr_customer**

[image: 1]

In the picture below, the user's search_counter is set to one and the three search columns have no value inside, so the code, based on my logic in my CASE, should have my "$search" value insert in "search1" and update search_counter from 1 to 2.

[image: 2]

PS I am aware of SQL Injection, please do not answer with a reminder because I am trying to get my code working first.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a SQL issue, it is a PHP issue.  The values you are replacing in your SQL Query should be prefixed with : instead of $.

```
     " UPDATE usr_customer
       SET search_counter = (CASE WHEN search_counter = 1 THEN 2
                                  WHEN search_counter = 2 THEN 3
                                  WHEN search_counter = 3 THEN 1 END),

           search1 = (CASE WHEN search_counter = 1 THEN :search END),
           search2 = (CASE WHEN search_counter = 2 THEN :search END),
           search3 = (CASE WHEN search_counter = 3 THEN :search END)
       WHERE usrcustomerid = :usrcustomerid "
```

See: [PHP Documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php)